# XCode 4.5 Analyze tool

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks

I build an iPhone app and notice that there is the Analyze tool in XCode.

I have this code:

```
View * view = [[View alloc]initWithFrame:self.view.frame title:currentItem.name id:currentItem.idStr];
self.menuView = [[MenuView alloc]init];
self.menuView.contentView = view;
[view release];
```

and the `View` Property:

```
@property (retain,nonatomic) MenuView * menuView;
```

And when i make a Analyze on the project i get this potential leak warning.
And i want to know if it's ok and the analyze just warn me? or i made a mistake with the code.

---

Edit

And if i do some thing like this :

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISlider *progressSlider;
```

.

```
self.progressSlider = [[[UISlider alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(58, 12, 191, 23)]autorealese];
[view addSubview:self.progressSlider];
```

and in the dealloc:

```
[progressSlider realese];
```

This is what i sould to do too? or it's wrong?

Comment: What warning are you getting?

Comment: Is it complaining that you're retaining menuView and never releasing? Or something else?

Comment: leak from view or menuView?

Comment: MTA, I have updated my answer for your edit. I really wish SO had an automatic system to notify the OP when edits are made like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you retain a property you should send it a release message in your dealloc method:

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [menuView release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Also, you alloc/init when you assign the menuView property.  The init method gives you a retain count of one.  Setting the property gives you a retain count of two.  You should have a matching number of releases.  Your setup code should look like this:

```
MenuView *m = [[MenuView alloc] init];
self.menuView = m;
[m release];
```

Comment: That unfortunately isn't the issue here. While yes, properties should be cleaned up in the destructor, he is leaking the memory much earlier than that.

Comment: Yeah, I spotted that and was slowly updating my post on an iPhone keyboard, hence the delay...

Answer (score 7):

You are leaking `self.menuView`, because the property is specified as `retain`. When you call `alloc` on an object, it's retain count is set to 1. When the property is assigned, it increases to two, with no balancing call to even it out..

The simplest fix is a call to `-autorelease`, as such:

```
self.menuView = [[[MenuView alloc] init] autorelease];
```

---

With your edit, yes, that code seems correct on the surface. My real question comes down to why are you still using manual reference counting? Yes - it is a good thing to understand on the surface, but apple has pretty much depracated it in favor of the newer ARC.

Comment: @0x7fffffff My official title is 'king of the runtime thing'.

Comment: for none of my answers I earned 5+ votes  in last 2 and half months :D

Comment: Haha, You're right, it probably is a "thing". Although, I've often thought of it as more of a whatchamajigger.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya it's all about timing. I picked a popular rising question apparently, and thus the upvotes come. If you look at my history, I haven't been answering many questions like this. I usually go for the higher effort, lower rep questions, because they intrigue me more. Unfortunately, I cannot pursue most of those questions while I'm bootcamp'd into windows.